# Cocos3D remove shades

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I have added a node(character) to my Cocos3D scene, as it can be seen in the image below, I am getting dark shades in the edges of the node. Is there a way to remove these shades in the edges?

[image: Its the image of the node added to Cocos3D scene]

Comment: Very strange. If you ZIP up a simple Xcode project that demonstrates this, and email it to support@brenwill.com, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Bill, we are checking if the issue is with the material of the node, will get back to you once I confirm.

Comment: You might be encountering a minifying issue, where the texture is being sampled in a dark area bounding the colored areas (and possibly blended with the color). This is more common as your object shrinks. Mipmaps will be created automatically if your texture has power-of-two dimensions. And look at the notes for the CC3Texture minifyingFunction property for sampling options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the above problem, first I had to set the ambient light of the scene in following way :

```
self.ambientLight = CCC4FMake(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0);
```

Then I had to set the diffuse color of the node which had the dark shades :

```
self.austenNode.diffuseColor=CCC4FMake(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
```

Thats all it worked :)

[image]